# Android HDPI resource not found, but it's there

Tags: android, android-resources, nine-patch, android-screen-support

on our app, with more than half a million downloads I've seeing from Google Play reports the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/trans_button_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02020b
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1961)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:653)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1961)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:458)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
... 38 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/transdark_active.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02020c
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2008)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:601)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1936)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/transdark_active.9.png
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:409)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1970)
... 48 more
```

for me, it seems to say that it tried to load `drawable/trans_button_bg.xml` which is a simple selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/transdark_active" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/transdark_active" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/trans_button" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

that calls the 9 patch transdark_active.9.png that is available on mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi:

[image]

that's just an example, stack, as I have other similar stacks for other assets failing to load.

The device breakdown for this error report is:

- Galaxy S4 (jflte) 66.7%
- Galaxy S2 (GT-I9100)  13.3%
- Galaxy Note II (t03g) 6.7%
- Galaxy S2 Plus (s2vep)    6.7%
- Desire HD (ace)

**so my question:**

Is it Samsung screwing up as usual, or am I missing something on the code?

Comment: I've been seeing similar occasional errors from Samsung devices..starred..

Comment: Why do you have 3 9-patches representing the same asset? I guess it's possible you'd need all 3, but often it isn't necessary. The Android docs say: " It must be saved with the extension .9.png, and saved into the res/drawable/ directory of your project." see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: @simekadam thanks. So maybe it's just Samsung screwing up.

Comment: @JustinPollard I know and agree with you, but that's a somewhat legacy code and a complete refactor n redesign is due. But meanwhile, I have to maintain it and avoid crashes.

Comment: Are you using 9-patches elsewhere in your app? If so, and you're not seeing crashes related to those 9-patches, maybe an analysis/ comparison of the offending 9-patch to the others will reveal the problem. I'd ask the questions: where are the other patches stored? Are there any errors in my transdark_active hdpi 9-patch? Does the resource ID in my error trace actually correspond to transdark_active? Etc.

Comment: try copying resources to a folder on desktop, then *clean project*, then copy resources one by one, then run *clean project* again